# LLDB "unable to find CIE"

Tags: c++, lldb

In LLDB, I regularly encounter the following error log, while trying to set break points.

```
(lldb) break set -n main
error: unable to find CIE at 0x00000020 for cie_id = 0x00000004 for entry at 0x00000020.
error: unable to find CIE at 0x00000058 for cie_id = 0x00000004 for entry at 0x00000058.
[...]
error: unable to find CIE at 0x00000ae8 for cie_id = 0x00000004 for entry at 0x00000ae8.
Breakpoint 1: where = spec_checker`main + 16 at main.cpp:19, address = 0x00000001000025f2
(lldb)
```

After some digging into the code of LLDB, I figured out that CIE means Common Information Entry and is related to the Dwarf debug format.

The break points seem to be set correctly, but this behaviour is annoying anyway and I wonder what I can do to fix it.

I build my executable with the "-g3" flag to generate the debug informations. Is it enough?

EDIT:

I'm building c++ code with g++ 4.2. I'm on Mac OS X 10.9 so the executable format is Mach-O.

Comment: Perhaps the libraries you're linking are not built with -g